# Google App Scripts URL Fetch HTTPResponse Class Objects

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, httpresponse, key-value, urlfetch

I'm using the following code in Google App Script:

```
    function SkiCheck() {
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://www.skibur.com");
      var ToSource = response.getAllHeaders().toSource();
      Logger.log(ToSource.keys());
    }
```

I get the following output:

```
    [14-06-30 20:06:46:849 EDT] ({ETag:"", 'X-Robots-Tag':"noarchive", 
    Expires:"Tue, 01 Jul 2014 00:06:51 GMT", 'X-XSS-Protection':"1; mode=block",
    'Alternate-Protocol':"80:quic,80:quic", 'Last-Modified':"Thu, 19 Jun 2014 
    07:54:48 GMT", Server:"GSE", 'Cache-Control':"public, max-age=5", 
    'X-Content-Type-Options':"nosniff", 'X-Frame-Options':"SAMEORIGIN", 'Transfer-
    Encoding':"chunked", Date:"Tue, 01 Jul 2014 00:06:46 GMT", 'Content-
    Encoding':"gzip", 'Content-Type':"text/html; charset=utf-8"})
```

How do I get the key's value from an Object created by getAllHeaders() by using the Google App Scripts URL Fetch HTTPResponse Class?

When I use:

```
    Logger.log(ToSource.keys("ETag"));
```

I get this error:

```
    TypeError: Cannot find function keys in object ({ETag:"", 'X-Robots-.... etc.
```

I need some help.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over the key-values pairs like this:

```
function SkiCheck() {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://www.skibur.com");
  var headers = response.getAllHeaders();
  for (var key in headers) {
    Logger.log(key + ': ' + headers[key]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked.  I wonder why the example is using toSource()?  Anyways, thanks for your help.